# Nagios how can I read a attribute value from a file in my command?

Tags: shell, nagios

I have written a bash script to get the authorization herader token to be written to the /usr/local/nagios/etc/resource.cfg file. The bash script works fine and in the resource.cfg the token value is saved as below,

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="Authorization: Bearer 38255d19-724a-4e2c-b8bc-1234retff13"
```

When configuring the nagios service I need to read the authorization header from the above file.

```
define command{
    command_name    check_post_https_with_args
    command_line    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -S -u $ARG1$ -k /usr/local/nagios/etc/resource.cfg echo $ACCESS_TOKEN  --method=POST --post $ARG2$ -T 'application/json' 
} 

define service{
    use             generic-service 
    host_name           www.cardgen.com
    service_description     post request checker
    is_volatile         0
    check_period            24x7
    check_interval                  1
    max_check_attempts      3
    normal_check_interval       1
    retry_check_interval        1
    contact_groups          admin_group
    notification_interval       120
    notification_period     24x7
    notification_options        w,u,c,r
    check_command check_post_https_with_args!/api/load/validatereadDetails=true!'{\"referenceId:145\",\"amount:500\"}'
}
```

This seems not to be working, can anyone guide me on how I can access the header value in the command by reading the file?

Answer (score 0):

Because `check_http` plugin doesn't support load your header directly from file you should use `resource.cfg` as storage for sensitive data like usernames or passwords in macros `$USERx$`.

So, your `resource.cfg` file should contain something like this:

```
$USER3$=Bearer
$USER4$=38255d19-724a-4e2c-b8bc-1234retff13
```

And this should be your command definition:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_post_https_with_args
    command_line    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -S -u $ARG1$ -k "Authorization: $USER3$ $USER4$"  --method=POST --post $ARG2$ -T 'application/json' 
}
```

PS: You can't store all of this in one macro, because Nagios macro can't contain *space* character.